# How to check if input string contains specific letters and is divisible by 3 in Python

Tags: python, validation, user-input, letter

I am writing a program that should check if:

- a user input string contains a specific word
- OR contains 4 designated characters and is divisible by 3.

I can get the specific string check and the divisibility check to work but I can't seem to get the letter check to work.

```py
validationcheck = False
while not validationcheck:
    InputSequence = input("Input: ")
    if (InputSequence == 'EXAMPLE' or len(InputSequence) % 3 == 0 and 'C', 'A', 'G', 'T', 't', 'g', 'a','c' in InputSequence):
        validationcheck = True
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
        InputSequence = input("Input: ")
```

My desired output would be that if the user types `EXAMPLE`, or they type a sequence of letters containing `C`, `A`, `G`, `T` that is divisible by 3, there would be no invalid input. Otherwise the program would print an invalid input message and prompt the user to re enter

Update - I ended up solving it but thanks for the reponses. I ended up using the following if it is helpful for anyone

```
            validationcheck = False
            while not validationcheck:
                InputSequence = input("Input: ")
                stringToCheck = InputSequence
                found = re.search("[CAGT]", stringToCheck)
                if len(InputSequence) % 3 == 0 and found:
                    validationcheck = True
```

Comment: Checking the specification on the second option: (1) must the input string contain all the designated characters, and (2) is it allowed to contain other characters? (since CAGT sounds like it might be a gene sequence which would not in fact have anything other than those characters, reinforced by the "divisibility by 3" which is amino acid coding length)

Answer (score 1):

I propose to do this in two steps: at first you check line lenght and if is `EXAMPLE` and than you should check for stranger chars inside your line.
To find characters inside a line you can iterate chars with a for loop:

```py
validationcheck = False
while not validationcheck:
    InputSequence = input("Input: ")
    if (InputSequence == 'EXAMPLE' or len(InputSequence) % 3):
        # check for single chars inside string
        input_ok = True
        for ch in InputSequence:
            # check if character is not in given options
            if (ch not in [...]):  # to be completed
                input_ok = False
        if (input_ok):
            validationcheck = True
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
        InputSequence = input("Input: ")
```

A simple note: for python label names use the snake case like `input_sequence` and not `InputSequence`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=any#any) to check if any of the letters (for letter in the string) are in `InputSequence` as lower case [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=lower#str.lower)

```
validationcheck = False
while not validationcheck:
    InputSequence = input("Input: ")
    if (InputSequence == 'EXAMPLE':
        validationcheck = True
   elif not len(InputSequence) % 3 and any(i in InputSequence.lower() for i in 'tgac'):
        validationcheck = True
   else:
        print("Invalid input")
        InputSequence = input("Input: ")
```

You can also search if the input is containing only the characters 't', 'g', 'a' or 'c' by using regex

```
import re
validationcheck = False
while not validationcheck:
    InputSequence = input("Input: ")
    if (InputSequence == 'EXAMPLE':
        validationcheck = True
   elif not len(InputSequence) % 3 and re.fullmatch(r'[tgac]+[\r\n]*', InputSequence.lower()):
        validationcheck = True
   else:
        print("Invalid input")
        InputSequence = input("Input: ")
```

The regex `[tgac]+[\r\n]*` is says "one of the 't' or 'g' or 'a' or 'c' 1 or infinity times, then line separation (can be '\n', '\r', '\r\n') 0 or infinity times". [more about regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re)

Comment: You should evaluate the programming level of the person that is asking and answer accordingly... both the pattern you gave are perfectly correct, but a bit difficult for entry level: `any(i in InputSequence.lower() for i in 'tgac'])` (btw you can remove a parenthesis as you will still have a generator) and `regex` concept/use

Comment: You're right!
I will add more details and explanations about the code I wrote.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need to ensure that in the second option, the string consists of **only** the characters `CAGT`. This is a different requirement of course - part of good programming is identifying and eliminating ambiguities in the specification.

Proceeding on that basis, the keyword option is more cleanly handled as a separate `if` statement, using `in` to check input against a keyword list. The following code uses [all( )](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#all) to ensure that non-keyword entries consist only of  characters `CAGT` in a list comprehension checking all individual characters against the allowed letters. The test here doesn't check that all of those letters are present (so `AGCAGC` would be passed valid despite having no `T`). Finally I gave divisibility by 3 its own error message since that is potentially harder to spot when looking at an otherwise-good entry.

You don't need a second input statement, since the loop will bring you back to that for invalid input.

```py
ExactKeywords = ['DOTHIS','DOTHAT']
validationcheck = False
while not validationcheck:
    InputSequence = input("Input: ").upper()
    if ( InputSequence in ExactKeywords ):
        validationcheck = True
    elif all(ch in 'CAGT' for ch in InputSequence):
        if len(InputSequence)%3 == 0:
            validationcheck = True
        else:
            print("Input string length not a multiple of 3")
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
```

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment above, ACGT sounds like it might denote a nucleotide sequence which would not have anything other than those characters, reinforced by the "divisibility by 3" which corresponds to amino acid coding ([codon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_code#Codons)) length.